# Named annotation without @Inject constructor not working

Tags: android, dagger-2

Class A

```
class A {
    }
```

Module class

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("one")
    fun provideA(): A{
        return A()
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("two")
    fun provideAA(): A{
        return A()
    }
}
```

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(activity: HomeActivity)

}
```

My Activity class

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    @Named("one")
    lateinit var one: A
    @Inject
    @Named("two")
    lateinit var two: A
    @Inject
    @Named("two")
    lateinit var three: A

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        var appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
        appComponent.inject(this)

         Log.d("HomeActivity", "1 $one")
         Log.d("HomeActivity", "2 $two")
         Log.d("HomeActivity", "3 $three")

    }
}
```

Above code works only if I add @Inject constructor to

> Class A

Otherwise getting error

> A cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an
>   @Provides-annotated method.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is your usage (either field or constructor injection)? This should also include the `@Named` annotation where class A is used

Comment: Use `@Inject @field:Named("one")` if using field injection.